# Mongoose how to update multiple subdocuments in different documents in one call - MERN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to make an API call via mongoose to update the date field of a batch of selected `Players` (schema below) `cards` subdocument to the current date.

The Player schema:

```
const playerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  cards: [{
    date: { type: Date, required: true },
    note: String
  }],
});
```

I created a checkbox where a user can select multiple `Players` (along with a specific 'card' subdocument from their `cards` array) and change the dates to be the same for those specific cards for all the selected `Players`. In react, I batched the corresponding ObjectIds together in the body and am sending the selected player/card combos in an array of objects that look as follows (where the number indicates the same grouped player & card subdocument ObjectId):

The array that I am sending to the server (accessible via req.body.cards):

```
[ {cardId: card1._id, playerId: player1._id},
  {cardId: card2._id, playerId: player2._id},
  {cardId: card3._id, playerId: player3._id} ]
```

In my Node/Express server `put` route, how would I go about updating all of those players and their specific card and giving them all the same date (Date.now()) asynchronously? In other words, how would I properly iterate over all the different playerIds and their respective cardId (preferably without any external libraries)?

Here's how I am updating a single card for a single player in my regular put route for editing the `cards` subdocument:

```
Player.findById(playerId)
  .then(player => {
    const card = player.cards.id(cardId);
    card.date = Date.now();

    player.save(
      (err, updatedCard) =>
        err
          ? console.log("Error in update card: " + err)
          : res.send(updatedCard)
    );
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work.

Single player can be updated with this query:-

```
Player.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: playerId, "cards._id": cardId },
  { $set: { "cards.$.date": Date.now() } }
);
```

Multiple players can be updated with this query

```
Player.update(
  { $or: [{ _id: player1Id, "cards._id": card1Id }, { _id: player2Id, "cards._id": card2Id }, { _id: player3Id, "cards._id": card3Id }] },
  { $set: { "cards.$.date": Date.now() } },
  { multi: true }
);
```

Positional operator $ will take care of updating the correct card inside the array with the given card Id.

Comment: thanks for this, very helpful, but when selecting more than one player for the multiple player update, I get `MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.` Also, we have to use `Player.updateMany` since update is deprecated.

Comment: Nevermind, I reconfigured my code to only send the subdocument card ids and used that array with a `{ "cards._id": cards}` query instead, which got it working